# Ethyl acetate produces red colour on ceric ammonium nitrate test

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, alcohols

When I did CAN test on ethyl acetate red colour was seen. I thought water may get added with Ethyl acetate to produce
[this compound](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12DSgYcC8nRILgrBt_Z0nYulD7rGSIryD/view?usp=drivesdk) which in turn gave red coloration but carbon should not make three bonds with oxygens easily.
What could be the possible explanation to this phenomena?

Comment: Water hydrolyses the ester to form an alcohol which responds to the CAN test.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ  could you please tell that alcohol's structure fromed in this process? I had thought of one, as mentioned in the question, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Since the ester is ethyl acetate, on hydrolysis, ethanol and acetic acid will be formed.

Comment: I had also thought about that but the solution of ethyl acetate with water did not change colour of blue litmus paper neither it gave effervescence on adding sodium bicarbonate.

Comment: In that case I think I might be wrong. Ester hydrolysis does require an acid catalyst which is absent here.

Comment: It could be that the ester gets reduced to two alcohols but I doubt how that would proceed either.